# How to count open push-notifications within' Google BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I need to develop an admin panel which can send and monitor push notifications. The data I gonna monitor for each message includes:

- amount of unique devices to send notification (with or no topic)
- amount of unique devices with recieved notification (with or no topic)
- amount of unique devices with opened notification (with no topic)

To collect this data I've decided to use Google BigQuery API. In [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#what-data-exported) I've founded query examples for first two items but I don't know how to count opened messages

So I need a help to solve this quizz. You can help me with one one of things:

- Query example to get amount of opend messages from BigQuery
- Demonstration of another wway to collect data if BigQuery is not appropriate for my purposes

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems that the OPEN status is not available in the information exported to BigQuery, the closes status to that event it's MESSAGE_DELIVERED

Comment: Any ideas how we could realese statistics to count opened delieverables?

Comment: In here you can open a feature request to include this field in Bigquery; however, I think that it could be a dependency from firebase in case that field doesn't exist in the source https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0